# How to add an NPM vuejs component at end of an HTML page

Tags: vue.js, npm

I have a PHP application built with an MVC framework.  On some pages I have complex, highly interactive components that have been created with `vuejs`.  The components are written as single-file-components, and bundled with webpack.  This works really well.  At the bottom of the html page I load the component with a line such as the following:

```
<script src="js/my_vue_component"></script>
```

Now I want to complement this by using Vue components on a more ad-hoc basis.  For example, I might use a Vue Date Picker component on a form.  In these cases, I don't want the overhead of creating single-file-components.

What's the best way to go about this?  Vue and it's third-party packages are managed via NPM.

I tried loading the code as follows:

```
<script>
    import Vue from "vue";
    import DatePicker from "vuejs-datepicker";
    const date1 = new Vue({
        el: '#respond_by',
        components: {
            'date-picker' : DatePicker
        }
    });
</script>
```

But I got an error saying that `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.

I then tried 'requiring' vue and vuejs-datepicker, but found that `require is not defined`.

Is there an easy way to go about this, without having to resort to a CDN, or should I just go back to single-file-components?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration

Inside your components script tag:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <date-picker></date-picker>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DatePicker from "vuejs-datepicker";    
export default {
  components: {
    'date-picker': DatePicker
  }
}
</script>
```

You can also register the component globally by declaring it in your main javascript file where you create Vue.

New components do **NOT** create a new Vue instance.